# sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated `s' command

Tags: bash

I'm running into the following error when running the following:

Command: `sed -i -e "s#\\\\n#\n#g" id_rsa`

Error:

```
sed -i -e s#\\n#
#g id_rsa
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated `s' command
```

There's clearly something wrong with `s` but I can't seem to figure out where? Does this need more escaping? It seems to be splitting up the command when it runs.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. What do you want to do? What should `\\\n` mean and whuy in the `Error` output there is `s#\\n#<newline>#g`? How is `\\\\n` substituted by `\\n`? Where is the newline coming from? How are you printing the `Error` part?  Is `\n` a newline or two characters \ and `n`?

Comment: You need to add a second backslash to the section newline as well, `sed -i -e "s#\\\\n#\\n#g" id_rsa`.

Comment: Can you please add your input and expected output?

Comment: @daniu That did the trick, thanks!

Comment: Folks, lets vote to close as a typo. But glad you solved your problem.